# how to add a subview that is in story board to another view that is in codes in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4, subviews

I have made a view that is in the story board and I want to add this view to the another view that is not in the story board and it has been created with codes 
    here is my codes :

```
@IBOutlet weak var sideBarView: UIView!
var sideBarViews = UIView()
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.sideBarViews.frame = CGRect(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.width  , y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
     self.sideBarViews.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 251/255, green: 251/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1.0)
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self.sideBarViews)
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarViews)
     self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarViews)
}
@IBAction func sideBarMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:
    {
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self.sideBarViews)
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarViews)
      self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarViews)
      self.sideBarViews.frame = CGRect(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 , y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
      self.view.addSubview(self.sideBarView)
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(self.sideBarView)
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarView)
      self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.sideBarView)
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: When you say 'made a view' is it completely stand alone in the storyboard or part of a view controller.  Maybe instead look at having a child view controller instead.  It depends really on what you want to use it for and are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I was wrong using xib file has solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing for UI components created in Storyboard inside a `UIViewController` is that they are not reusable and not subclassable. Moreover, `UIViewControllers` inside a specific storyboard can not be subclassed and reused later as other classes as well.

I suggest looking into creating a `.xib` file with a dedicated `UIView`subclass so you can reuse it anytime.

Here's a nice tutorial for that - https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: But I have a table view in that view so I need to use that view in this class 
in fact I have a tabBar and I want to have a slide menu inFront of that But the tab Bar is inFront of that so I made a view with code that will be infront of that tabBar and now I wanted to add the table view in this view that you can find this question link too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127021/how-to-place-uiview-infront-of-view-that-is-infront-of-tabbar-and-special-tabbar

Comment: If you are using it for a slide in menu then instead of having a simple view I would develop it as a full view controller and then present that as needed.